# how do I average three columns where the criteria changes each month..ie last three monthly data

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have three columns for each month. I need to average the value in the third column of each month for the last three entries. Can I write a formula that will select the last three entries in the designated range and calculate the average.? And to do this for multiple rows where the data may not be in the same columns?
My level of skill in using Excel is very limited, but I am trying to learn, I would very much appreciate any help that may be forthcoming.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AVERAGE() function in a cell on the same row. The arguments for the function will be the cells you wish to average.

Can be a series of cells (A1,B1,C1....) or a range (A1:C1). If you use cells from all over the spreadsheet. The copy function uses the relative position by default.

Once you have the function working in a particular row, you may copy that formula down to the other rows in the spreadsheet. Excel will automatically change the formula to include the corresponding cells from the same row the formula is being copied to.

For additional info on this function, visit:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/average-function-HP010062482.aspx

Comment: ioMatrix, thank you for the answer, however I obviously didn't make the question clear. I as data is added I want the average to be of the last three entries in the row where ever they are. So that if there are entries for Sept/Oct and Nov it will average that data, however if the is no data in Oct, it will average August/Sept and Nov. I can resolve the other issue of every third column by extracting the data to elsewhere and completing the function there and returning the result to the original location.  Sorry if it wasn't clear first time.

Comment: Excel isn't the best when it comes to what you are asking it to do. You are asking for it to take data and if a certain condition exists (no entry for a month) then get more data and so on.

Comment: You could use if statements to allow for multiple situations...but that limits the possibilities to 7 (the limit for nested if statements).

The other alternative is to create a separate sheet (or if you have room the active one). Each column would test a different condition. If the condition is true, post the average, if not post a zero. Then use sum to add up the in the row and that's the answer.

Comment: If I could see the sheet, maybe the solution is easier than I think. I don't fully understand the way the data is laid out.

Comment: The use is a handicap sheet for a gun club.. the handicap is based on their three past shoots. as not everyone shoots every month the data is taken from their last three shoots. The worksheet doesn't yet exist, I can input the data in any form that makes the job easier.